# Darboux coordinates on a holomorphic symplectic manifold?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, symplectic-geometry

I know the theorem of Darboux, that every (real) symplectic manifold $(M, \omega)$ admits charts, where $\omega$ has the simple form
$$ \omega = \sum_{i=1}^n dx_i \wedge dy_i.$$
Is this also true for complex manifolds, where $\omega$ is a holomorphic $2$-form? I.e. can the Darboux charts be choosen in a *holomorphic* way?

Comment: Not when the manifold is hyperkahler; then the corresponding Kahler metric would be flat, which can't happen. If the holomorphic symplectic form has nothing to do with a metric, then I guess you could look at the proof of Darboux's theorem and see what works.

Comment: @GunnarÞórMagnússon Can you explain how Darboux coordinates imply that the Kähler metric is flat? I still have some trouble relating the symplectic form (which has type $(2,0)$) to the Kähler metric (which has type $(1,1)$).

Comment: I'm sorry, I misremembered and was confused about the relationship between the holomorphic symplectic and hyperkahler structures.

Comment: For a Kähler manifold the symplectic form is known as the Kähler form which in local coordinates can be written $\omega=\frac{i}{2}\sum dz_i\wedge d\bar z_i=\sum d x_i\wedge dy_i$. This is a (1,1)-form and in particular a non.degenerate 2-form. The Kähler form is in some sense easier to deal with since you can write it in as a function of a Kähler potential $\omega=i\partial \bar \partial f$, which in local coordinates is $f=\frac{1}{2}\sum z_i\bar z_i$. If by holomorphic form you mean a $\bar \partial$-closed $(2,0)$-form that is no longer true.

Comment: @NIntegrate You are wrong about the local form. This seems to assume a flat Kähler metric, no?

Comment: @TedShifrin I believe you are correct. As I understand it you can do so for each point $p\in M$, by diagonalising the hermitian matrix, but  not in a neighbourhood. There seems to be a detailed answer to this on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/254563/kahler-version-of-darbouxs-theorem/254674

Comment: @NIntegrate The Kähler condition says that there is the holomorphic analogue of normal coordinates at $p$, in which the metric agrees with the identity to order $2$ at $p$.